# Not Able to debug remote side application on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging, weblogic-10.x

I have a J2EE module running on remote server and i m trying to Debug it from my eclipse using  remote application debuging Configuration.

Now acc to articles i have read, i understood following points

1) As my code is deployed on Weblogic server, i give a cmd from command prompt to start my module, in that command i explicitly added debug option.

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTIONS%
```

2) now in my eclipse i created a debug conf with same port 8787 and my IP and gave all source files for my Module

and now i put a break poitn & run my eclipse in debug mode, application on server is already running.
All i get is weblogic kernel default threads but not the one i put my breakpoint on.

`framework [Remote Java Application]

    Oracle JRockit(R)[10.203.139.61:8787]

        Thread [Main Thread] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [(Signal Handler)] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [(OC Main Thread)] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [(Code Generation Thread 1)] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [(Code Optimization Thread 1)] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [(VM Periodic Task)] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [(Attach Listener)] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [(Sensor Event Thread)] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [VM JFR Buffer Thread] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [Timer-0] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [Timer-1] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [JFR request timer] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [weblogic.time.TimeEventGenerator] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [JMAPI event thread] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [weblogic.timers.TimerThread] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [VDE Transaction Processor Thread] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [DoSManager] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [Thread-12] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [OracleTimeoutPollingThread] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [Dispatcher-Thread-13] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [Dispatcher-Thread-14] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [Thread-16] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [Thread-17] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [SnmpSession-Runnable] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [TrapInformProcessor0] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [ResponseProcessor0] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [TimerProcessor0] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [PollingProcessor0] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [MasterAgentXServer: null:1705] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [ClientNotifForwarder-1] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [DynamicListenThread[Default]] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [DynamicSSLListenThread[DefaultSecure]] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)

        Daemon Thread [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (Running)`

i cannot find anywhere the thread realted to my breakpoint.. and none of the above

> Drop To Frame

Comment: Your configuration looks fine to me. Probably you have already tried this: can you add a breakpoint somewhere in your code where you are sure it is executed? Maybe the breakpoint you have added is in an area of the code that does not run. Safest way to try is somewhere in the initialization, but then you have to change your java_options to suspend=y so that in startup your server waits for eclipse to start the debug session

Answer (score 0):

After a day of.. trying i finally was able to hit my breakpoints, and yes i had to set **"suspend =y"** this help me syncing my app with eclipse.
the steps shown in this question are correct and can be used by anyone whose trying for same.

problem for me was that i got multiple modules and the core module is the only one where break point works, others are just third party code.